# Exploding a url in PHP

Tags: php

How can I obtain just the ID portion of this url.

```
281805943&amp;buying=true&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=false&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;color=e55b5b&amp;color_theme=f5f5f5&amp;auto_play=
```

I currently have exploded the url which contained the API path + the actual link but trying to obtain the ID `281805943` has proven to be a little harder, please note that we can't just echo out `281805943` because I am scraping a website and gathering their urls, this id will be different every time how ever the format will remain the same.

Original URL format looks like the following.

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/281805943&amp;buying=true&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=false&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;color=e55b5b&amp;color_theme=f5f5f5&amp;auto_play=
```

I've currently exploded it using this

```
$d2 = $dl->src;
$test = explode("/", $d2);
$test[8];
```

Comment: is the ID always going after `tracks` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always **exactly** the same then you can do the below using the `$test[8]` variable you already have:

```
parse_str($test[8], $output);
$id = key($output);
```

Or a single liner:

```
$id = explode('&', $test[8])[0];
```

There are many ways to skin a cat

Comment: Appreciate that help my friend, nice sense of humor also. I too enjoy skinning cats.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for parse_url, from the PHP docs....

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
$blob = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $blob['query'];  //arg=value
echo $blob['anchor'];  //anchor
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly pretty but it does find the id

```
$url="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/281805943&amp;buying=true&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=false&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;color=e55b5b&amp;color_theme=f5f5f5&amp;auto_play=";
preg_match('@/tracks/(\d+)&@',$url,$matches);
echo 'id='.$matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ID is always between 'tracks/' and '&amp':

```
$url = 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/281805943&amp;buying=true&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=false&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;color=e55b5b&amp;color_theme=f5f5f5&amp;auto_play=';

$pattern = "/(tracks\/)([\d]+)(\&amp)/";
preg_match($pattern,$url,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

var_dump($matches[2][0]);
```